# SQL Query - is it possible to add a Grand Total to this query?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2016

SQL Server 2016 Enterprise, using SSMS...

I have a query as thus:

```
WITH SUMS AS (
SELECT
    dbo.BillingActivity.BillingCodeId AS [Billing Code],
    dbo.Clients.ClientName AS [Client Name],
    dbo.BillingCodes.Name AS [Billing Code Name]
    , SUM(CASE WHEN Details LIKE '%"LW":"True"%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [LW]
    , SUM(CASE WHEN Details LIKE '%"MHN":"True"%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [MHN]
    , SUM(CASE WHEN Details LIKE '%"EPAP":true%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [EPAP]
    , SUM(CASE WHEN Details LIKE '%"EPAP (old)":"True"%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [EPAPOld]
FROM dbo.BillingActivity
INNER JOIN dbo.BillingCodes ON dbo.BillingActivity.BillingCodeId=dbo.BillingCodes.Id
INNER JOIN dbo.Clients ON dbo.BillingActivity.ClientId=dbo.Clients.ID
WHERE dbo.BillingActivity.RecordDateTime BETWEEN '2017-11-09' AND '2017-11-10'
GROUP BY dbo.BillingActivity.BillingCodeId, dbo.BillingCodes.Name, dbo.Clients.ClientName)
SELECT 
    [Billing Code],
    [Client Name],
    [Billing Code Name],
    [LW],
    [MHN],
    [EPAP],
    [EPAPOld],
    SUM(LW+MHN+EPAP+EPAPOld) OVER (PARTITION BY [Billing Code Name]) AS [Billing Code Total]
FROM SUMS
ORDER BY [Client Name] ASC, [Billing Code Name] ASC
```

Which gives me the following results: (the table refused to line up correctly on here, thus the image:

[image]

What I'm wondering whether is possible (internet research thus far would say no) is whether I can add to this query to create a 9th column which will show the total of all amounts in the column Billing Code Total.  It doesn't matter what row it shows in, nor does it matter if the same amount shows in all rows, I just need to see the total of that column somewhere.

Please note that the Billing Code Total name is an alias.  This proposes an additional challenge.

Many thanks.

Comment: Are familiar with [`ROLLUP`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189305(v=sql.90).aspx)?

Comment: This sounds like a job for your client program.

Comment: Which dbms??????

Comment: @PM77-1 I am not.  I will read up on that one now.  Thanks!

Comment: @Eric, sorry, I've edited the post to clarify.  SQL Server 2016 Enterprise with SSMS.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn not sure what that means but sounds interesting lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need an `over()` clause for the `billing code total` but you do for the other column you want, something like this:

```
WITH
      sums AS (
                  SELECT
                        dbo.BillingActivity.BillingCodeId                                     AS [billing code]
                      , dbo.Clients.ClientName                                                AS [client name]
                      , dbo.BillingCodes.Name                                                 AS [billing code name]
                      , SUM(CASE WHEN Details LIKE '%"LW":"True"%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)         AS [lw]
                      , SUM(CASE WHEN Details LIKE '%"MHN":"True"%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)        AS [mhn]
                      , SUM(CASE WHEN Details LIKE '%"EPAP":true%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)         AS [epap]
                      , SUM(CASE WHEN Details LIKE '%"EPAP (old)":"True"%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [epapold]
                  FROM dbo.BillingActivity
                  INNER JOIN dbo.BillingCodes ON dbo.BillingActivity.BillingCodeId = dbo.BillingCodes.Id
                  INNER JOIN dbo.Clients ON dbo.BillingActivity.ClientId = dbo.Clients.ID
                  WHERE dbo.BillingActivity.RecordDateTime BETWEEN '2017-11-09' AND '2017-11-10'
                  GROUP BY
                        dbo.BillingActivity.BillingCodeId
                      , dbo.BillingCodes.Name
                      , dbo.Clients.ClientName
            )
SELECT
      [Billing Code]
    , [Client Name]
    , [Billing Code Name]
    , [LW]
    , [MHN]
    , [EPAP]
    , [EPAPOld]
    , LW + MHN + EPAP + EPAPOld AS [billing code total]
    , SUM(LW + MHN + EPAP + EPAPOld) OVER() as all_sum
FROM sums
ORDER BY
      [Client Name] ASC
    , [Billing Code Name] ASC
```

Comment: This works perfectly, Used.  Well done and thank you.  Marked as answer.